# PHP - How can i use str_replace in that situation?

Tags: php

i have a column called Status in my table, and the possible values for this column are 1 or 0, 1 means that the row is activated and 0 means that the row is disabled.

But inside my backoffice, i have one html table to edit all the values inside this table.

To edit the values, the admin just need to select some rows(i'm using checkboxes), and click at the button to edit.

[image]

This button will show a new html table , inside this html table, i inserted all the values that i have inside my database table, into textboxes to change and edit.

The problem is that i need to show the current Status column value, example:

The status is activated, the value from status is 1.

The value will appear like this:

[image]

To change that, i used str_replace

```
if ($val['status'] == '1'){

$val['status'] = str_replace("1","Active","1");

}else{

$val['status'] = str_replace("0","Disable","0");

}
```

But when i submit the str_replace changes the value, and sends to my database Active instead 1, or Disabled instead 0.

I'm using a selectbox to chose if the status must be active or disabled

```
  <select name='u_status[".$val['id']."]' class='txtedit'>
  <option value=".$val['status']." style='display:none;'>".$val['status']."</option>
  <option value='1'>Active</option>
  <option value='0'>Disabled</option>
  </select>
```

Thank you.

Comment: remove str_replace block completely - it's useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array with the statuses:

```
$status = array(
    'Disabled',
    'Enabled'
);
```

Then use `$val['status']` as the key to get the value you want from that array:

```
<option value=".$val['status']." style='display:none;'>".$status[$val['status']]."</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use str_replace. This is just a boolean.

```
$val['status'] = ($val['status'] == '1' ? 'Active' : 'Disabled');
```

or even:

```
if ($val['status'] == '1') {
    $val['status'] = 'Active';
} else {
    $val['status'] = 'Disabled';
}
```